# How to reduce redundancy in multiple if-elif blocks?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, redundancy

I'm writing a "quiz game" using a GUI package called *Draw.py*.
I'm new to this and I don't really know how to reduce redundancy of my code.

The code works perfectly but I know it's not completely neat.
Here's what I would like to reduce:

```
def question1():
    question("Which device would \n you most want to have?") #draws #question
    answer1()  #draws the answer boxes. 
    mouseclicks = 0

    while mouseclicks != 1:
        if Draw.mousePressed():   #checks if the user clicks.

            xCoord= Draw.mouseX()   #check x-y coordinates
            yCoord= Draw.mouseY()

            if  xCoord >= 91 and xCoord <= 390 and yCoord >= 400 \
                and  yCoord <= 552:
                ChooseAnswer(88,400,300,150)  #Chosen answer, turns green #when user clicks
                characters["question 1"]["PC"] += 1  
                mouseclicks += 1    
                answer1()

            elif xCoord >= 601 and xCoord <= 900  and yCoord >= 402 \
            and yCoord <= 550:
                ChooseAnswer(600,400,300,150)
                characters["question 1"]["BJ"] += 1   
                mouseclicks += 1 
                answer1()

            elif xCoord >= 92 and xCoord <= 388  and yCoord >= 602 \
            and yCoord <= 750:
                ChooseAnswer(88,600,300,150)
                characters["question 1"]["Mr.P"] += 1                
                mouseclicks += 1    
                answer1()

            elif xCoord >= 602 and xCoord <= 902  and yCoord >= 603 \
            and yCoord <= 750:
                ChooseAnswer(600,600,300,150)
                characters["question 1"]["Diane"] += 1
                mouseclicks += 1
                answer1()
```

I created a dictionary and everytime the user clicks within certain coordinates one of the keys in the dictionary goes up by one. At the end, the key with the highest value is the winner.

Comment: Esther, have you tried to implement some unit tests for your code? I suggest try to exercise some Test-Driven Development techniques for your coding skill improvement, if you think it can help.

Comment: You can refactor your code for parametrized functions, removing repetitive coed into these functions. Create parameters for what changes.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to create lists of coordinates, arguments for `ChooseAnswer` and keys of `characters` like this:

```
coordinates = [(91, 390, 400, 552),
               (601, 900, 402, 550),
               (92, 388, 602, 750),
               (602, 902, 603, 750)]
answers = [(88, 400, 300, 150),
           (600, 400, 300, 150),
           (88, 600, 300, 150),
           (600, 600, 300, 150)]
keys = ["PC", "BJ", "Mr.P", "Diane"]
```

and then iterate over `coordinates`, check which ones satisfy your conditions, and finally call `ChooseAnswer` with corresponding arguments and increment a value of `characters` for a corresponding key:

```
for index, coordinate in enumerate(coordinates):
    if (coordinate[0] <= xCoord <= coordinate[1]
            and coordinate[2] <= yCoord <= coordinate[3]):
        ChooseAnswer(*answers[index])
        characters["question 1"][keys[index]] += 1
        mouseclicks += 1    
        answer1()
```